# Event handler that executed only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

Is there a directive or a way to implement in AngularJS what [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function achieves with jQuery?

i.e., to attach an event to an element that gets executed only once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wire up an ng-click to the element you want, then in the ng-click function in your controller have a variable that you toggle to a state that would make the ng-click no longer execute something like

```
var firedOnce = false;
scope.myClickFunction = function(){
    if(firedOnce){ return; }
    //other code
    firedOnce = true;
}
```

You could also wire up a directive to do it too.

**edit**: Jsfiddle of directive method: http://jsfiddle.net/4hDb3/

Comment: Yeah, thats what I ended up doing. Although, I am hoping for more directives in upcoming versions from the AngularJS team to handle events. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I highly doubt angular will add a one-off directive like what you're describing. That's more of a specific requirement. I've modified my answer for you if you want to do the directive though.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, for the directive. That does it for me :)