# Register event listener only once in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm broadcasting an event from my navbar controller to another controller, but if I initialize  the controller multiple times (when I'm going front and back through the application) the function that executes on my `$on` event runs multiple times because it's registered multiple times.

```
$rootScope.$on('submitBookingDialog', function(){
    submitBookingDialog();
});
```

How can I prevent the `submitBookingDialog()` to happen more than once?

I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18355215/1020551), but I don't know if it's ideal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Event handler thats executed only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449076/angularjs-event-handler-thats-executed-only-once)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unsubscribe to a broadcast event in angularJS. How to remove function registered via $on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, do you need to send the event on the `$rootScope`? If not, then you could just register your event handler on the `$scope`. The event handler will be destroyed whenever your controller scope is destroyed. You would then send the event via `$scope.$emit` or `$scope.$broadcast` depending on your controller hierarchy.

That being said, all you need to do to destroy your event listener is call the deregistration function that is returned when registering the listener:

```
var offSubmitBookingDialog = $rootScope.$on('submitBookingDialog', function(){
    submitBookingDialog();
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    // Call the deregistration function when the scope is destroyed
    offSubmitBookingDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 17):

This seems to do it for me:

```js
var removeListener = $rootScope.$on('submitBookingDialog', function(){
    submitBookingDialog();

    // Remove listener
    removeListener();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this correct answer. The $on operation returns the function signature, therefore you just call it when appropriate to remove it.

Comment: Thanks. This is the way to do it. You can find a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg#14898795)

Answer (score 6):

For posterity I ended up doing this:

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.once = function(e, func) {
        var unhook = this.$on(e, function() {
            unhook();
            func.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    };
})
```

Because I kept needing to do this in a few places this just ended up being cleaner.
With that on your app module you can now just call `once` instead of `$on`:

```
$rootScope.once('submitBookingDialog', function() {
    submitBookingDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar situation, so I wrote a small library to make pub/sub stuff easier.

https://github.com/callmehiphop/hey

Comment: :D Glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you shoud unsubscribe on controller destroy event

```
var removeSubmitBookingDialog = $rootScope.$on('submitBookingDialog',submitBookingDialog);
$scope.$on("$destroy", removeSubmitBookingDialog);
```