# Angular, trigger input change event only once

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am using angular-formly plugin to display my form. I have an input field. When user enters a character in the field, i will add only one more input box. So, `onKeyUp` listener must be triggered only once like `$.once` in jquery.

I am not sure, how to do this with Angular-formly. Plunker code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iiJ8Uuafl3yt1uxs76qN?p=preview) adds a new field for every character which is not desired.

Comment: a workaround mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449076/angularjs-event-handler-thats-executed-only-once

Comment: `$touched` is triggered when you input's value has changed in the first place, more  [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025102/angular-difference-between-pristine-dirty-and-touched-untouched)

Comment: Can't you just add an if to check the length of $scope.fields?

Comment: thank you all. i was trying to repeat adding input fields when the user reaches/enters in the last input field. Bhabishya's answer helped me, and here is the new plunker, https://plnkr.co/edit/iiJ8Uuafl3yt1uxs76qN?p=preview